# Ionic - directive in modal not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a modal with OpenLayers map directive, which works fine except in modal window. I tried loading with controller but nothing.

This is directive i created, as you can see it's simple as possible:

```
.directive('olMap', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="map" class="map"></div>',

    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      var map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
            })
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 4
          })
      });
    }
}
});
```

Why is that?

Comment: What doesn't work? What did work? Any errors?

Comment: @devqon Doesn't get loaded, i get html tag replaced with directive html but the map. That happend only in modal, in other view it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to bootstrap? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization

Comment: I don't think you have to name your `link` function, try remove the `postLink`

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but it doesn't change anything. Works fine on templates except in modal window. Really strange behaviour.

Comment: Yes Directives are not working in ionic modals. Reading the log. If i have a 2 way data bind to modal ( = ) then nothing gets compiled in the directive and it throws an error. Check my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526884/directive-in-ionicmodal-complies-first-before-even-controller-loaded