# Directive In ionicModal complies first, before even controller loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a $ionicModal and inside that I have a directive, lets call it `<scrap-link-cards>` , this takes in the a two way data bind value of a scope object. This is inside a $ionicModal template:-->

```
<scrap-link-cards datasource=(updates.update_links)> </scrap-link-cards>
```

This is my full directive:

```
.directive('scrapLinkCards', function ($log) {
        var controller = function ($scope) {
            $scope.links = angular.copy($scope.datasource); //undefined
            $scope.LastIndex = $scope.links.length - 1;
        };
       var templateUrl ='/path/to/template' ;

        return{
            restrict :'E',
            controller: controller,
            scope: {
              datasource :'='
            },
            templateUrl : templateUrl
        }
    })
```

This is my templateUrl's Template:

```
<div class="scrapLinks">
    <h3>{{links[LastIndex].title}}</h3>
    <p>{{links[LastIndex].description}}</p>
</div>
```

Please NOTE that, this is inside a $ionicModal:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('path/to/template/html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function ($ionicModal) {
        $scope.ReadMore = $ionicModal;
});
```

Now here is my problem, **since its inside a $ionicModal**, the HTML gets complied, before angular can have access to (updates.updates_links). I get a undefined object at `$scope.links`. How can I workaround this?  I have tried **using link function** of directive, (moved all the logic in link) still.. I think $ionicModal templates are compiled before controller loaded ? Is it?

Comment: I'm maybe wrong, but this synthax seems odd to me ... datasource=(updates.update_links). Shall not it be : datasource="updates.update_links"

Comment: just some clarifications... Where and how do you activate your modal? Does the modal itself contains the directive? Thanks

Comment: @aorfevre yes, but it works this way too.

Comment: yes the modal contains the directive. I am calling it from a click event on from my controller.

Answer (score 1):

The only work around I managed to create is to stop the compile function to ever reaching the Modal's directive. Using a `ng-if` and wrapping the directive with a `div`.

In the Modal's template :

`<div ng-if="updates">
<scrap-link-cards datasource=(updates.update_links)> </scrap-link-cards> 
</div>`

This way the complier leaves the directive and only complies when the user opens the modal.

Comment: Thanks, this gets the job done. It seems like a bit of an anti-pattern, but given the very deficient modal implementation in ionic, I'll take it. You should be able to simplify a bit with ng-if on the same element as your directive.